# Implemtation of the odoo tags

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

Its a theoretical related question.
I have been working on migrated project from V7 to V13.
I would like to understand the implementation of history_back and history_first. In V7 its been used to redirect pages. But the same not working in V13.

Is there any implementation process to make it work in V13?